# Meteor and Polymer, what is causing this behaviour?

Tags: meteor, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to start using Polymer with Meteor, but have seen the following behaviour that I can't explain.

To reproduce git clone https://github.com/JeremyKells/meteor-polymer-testing.git and run meteor.

This is just the app created with:

```
meteor create testpoly
```

and then adding the polymer components with bower:

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-elements
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements
```

and adding the  section to the code .

As is this runs ok, but if you remove the comments around either of these two lines:

```
<!-- <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html"> -->
<!-- <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-action-dialog.html"> -->
```

The app shows the normal meteor counter app twice like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAv7Z.png

Why is this happening?  How do I stop this?

Further info following Guissouma's response.  I'm running this on Ubuntu 15.04, and mainly testing with chrome.  When the UI elements are duplicated, clicking either button only updates the second 'counter', the first count remains at zero.

And on Firefox in this same environment, there is just the one set of UI elements, but the button does not work.

i.stack.imgur.com/bqumz.png

Trying with both Safari and Chrome on iphone connecting to this server give same results as firefox: It looks ok, but the button doesn't update the count value.

Comment: Hello, I tested the project with meteor on windows, it works as expected! I remove the comments from headers.html The app shows the normal meteor counter app.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313557/how-i-use-web-components-in-meteorjs/34450705#34450705), maybe helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a case of getting the import links wrong, when changing from Polymer 0.5 to Polymer 1.0.
It should be:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
```

While I'm still confused as to why this caused html tags to be duplicated, and why this doesn't throw an error in the browser, it all works when I get the code correct!

Comment: It's because Meteor is returning its main page when there's a 404 error. I'm having the same problem with `paper-icon-button` which references `paper-radio-button-behavior` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the project with meteor on windows, it works as expected! I remove the comments from headers.html The app shows the normal meteor counter app.

[image]

On ubuntu 15.0.4 with firefox the button seem not working, this is due to the js file webcomponents.js imported on headers.html file.
Try to comment this line on headers.html and test again.

```
<!-- <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script> -->
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Guissouma, thanks for testing!  Can you check if the button updates the counter?  I'll update the question with details on the environment I am using (ubuntu 15.04, chrome browser)

Comment: Yes the button updates the counter, it works too on firefox and chrome. try to remove cache of the browser.

Comment: Hello, try to comment this line on your headers.html file! <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>, the butoon should work then on firefox on ubuntu 15.0.4.

Comment: That line is essential to using polymer.  I tried switching it for the alternative webcomponents-lite.min.js, but still have the same result, and an error in the browser console:  
    Uncaught TypeError: t.log.split is not a function
I'm getting the same results with windows, and have also deployed this to polymertesting.meteor.com

Comment: On chromium on linux ubuntu I have the duplicate body, I didn't figure out the cause of this strange behaviour! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Make sure your bower dependencies for Polymer and PaperElements are up to date. (i.e. use #^1.0.0 instead of #1.0.0.)

## Details

The root cause of this issue is two fold:

1. Meteor responds with the content of the main page even when there is no resource at the path request, but it [does not use a 404 (Not Found) status code](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1055).
2. HTML imports will include a referenced document into the page [unless the response is an error](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#fetching-import).

It doesn't even matter if you're using Polymer. The following Meteor app will exhibit the duplication behavior:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="bad-link.html">
</head>
<body>
  I'm Duplicated!<br>
</body>
```

The solution is to make sure your HTML imports are valid.

In my case, `paper-icon-button.html` had an import for `paper-behaviors/paper-radio-button-behavior.html` which doesn't exist in the latest version of `paper-behaviors`.

The reason for the inconsistency is because `paper-icon-button` was locked at version `#1.0.0` but its own bower dependencies referenced `paper-behaviors#^1.0.0` which means [the latest version >= 1.0.0 and < 2.0.0](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004).

The solution was to change my bower dependencies versions to use the [semver caret syntax](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) as well.

```json
{
  "dependecies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#^1.0.0"
  }
}
```